# Vector operations by time intervals , in R ??, aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate, time-series, zoo

I have a time series (zoo with index type chron) and I need to calculate `cummax(mydata)-mydata` on every day separately, in a new zoo object.

I've tried this:

```
aggregate(mydata, as.date, cummax)
```

but `aggregate` can only produce a single scalar result for each subset instead of a vector.  I've read that maybe `tapply`, `lapply`, `plyr`, `cut`, or `rollapply` could do it, but I couldn't get them to work.

Comment: Sample data would go a long way in helping the experts (not me!) here help you.

Answer (score 1):

`zoo` has a `cummax` method, so you shouldn't have any issues getting a `zoo` result.  Perhaps you're making this more difficult than it is... is this what you want?

```
> set.seed(21)
> z <- zoo(runif(10),as.chron(Sys.Date()-10:1))
> merge(z,cummax=cummax(z),diff=cummax(z)-z)
                  z    cummax      diff
08/09/10 0.66754012 0.6675401 0.0000000
08/10/10 0.93521022 0.9352102 0.0000000
08/11/10 0.05818433 0.9352102 0.8770259
08/12/10 0.61861583 0.9352102 0.3165944
08/13/10 0.17491846 0.9352102 0.7602918
08/14/10 0.03767539 0.9352102 0.8975348
08/15/10 0.52531317 0.9352102 0.4098971
08/16/10 0.28218425 0.9352102 0.6530260
08/17/10 0.49904520 0.9352102 0.4361650
08/18/10 0.63382510 0.9352102 0.3013851
```

Since that's pretty easy, I'm guessing your time-series is an intraday frequency.  If that's the case, the code is more involved, but this should do the trick:

```
> require(xts)  # for the endpoints() function
> set.seed(21)
> z <- zoo(runif(10),as.chron(Sys.Date()-seq(0.5,3,length.out=10)))
> ep <- endpoints(z,"days")
> Z <- lapply(1:(length(ep)-1), function(x) cummax(z[(ep[x]+1):ep[x+1]]))
> Z <- do.call(rbind, Z)
> merge(z,Z,Z-z)
                            z         Z     Z - z
(08/16/10 00:00:00) 0.8493961 0.8493961 0.0000000
(08/16/10 06:40:00) 0.9860037 0.9860037 0.0000000
(08/16/10 13:20:00) 0.1721917 0.9860037 0.8138120
(08/16/10 20:00:00) 0.1018046 0.9860037 0.8841991
(08/17/10 02:40:00) 0.9186834 0.9186834 0.0000000
(08/17/10 09:20:00) 0.9596138 0.9596138 0.0000000
(08/17/10 16:00:00) 0.1844608 0.9596138 0.7751531
(08/17/10 22:40:00) 0.6992523 0.9596138 0.2603615
(08/18/10 05:20:00) 0.2524456 0.2524456 0.0000000
(08/18/10 12:00:00) 0.7861149 0.7861149 0.0000000
```

Comment: Hello I will study your answer, thanks. meanwhile I got to do this tapply(z,as.Date(index(z)), cummax) but it gives me a list and when I try to convert it to a zoo object, with unlist or unsplit, I get strange things with dates. cheers

Comment: That's simpler than my answer.  You're just missing the `do.call` part : `Z <- do.call(rbind, tapply(z, as.Date(index(z)), cummax))`

Answer (score 0):

A crude method: make a matrix with rows or columns corresponding to the chunks over which the calculation is to be done, then use `apply`

```
x <- rnorm(240) # imagine this to be 10 days of hourly data
xm <- matrix(x, ncol=24, byrow=TRUE)
daily.avg <- apply(xm, 1, mean)
plot(x)
lines(12 + seq(1,240,24), daily.avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its can be done in one line using ave:

```
> library(zoo)
> set.seed(123)
> z <- zoo(rnorm(10), chron(0:9/5))
>
> ave(coredata(z), as.Date(time(z)), FUN = cummax) - z
(01/01/70 00:00:00) (01/01/70 04:48:00) (01/01/70 09:36:00) (01/01/70 14:24:00) (01/01/70 19:12:00) (01/02/70 00:00:00) (01/02/70 04:48:00) 
           0.000000            0.000000            0.000000            1.488200            1.429421            0.000000            1.254149 
(01/02/70 09:36:00) (01/02/70 14:24:00) (01/02/70 19:12:00) 
           2.980126            2.401918            2.160727
```